# Плавный переход/анимация при hover на иконку

Tags: html, css, css-animation

Внутри блока есть спозиционированная иконка, при наведении на которую появляется текст и бордер. Суть в том, что нужно не просто появление этих элементов - они должны как бы выезжать из-под неё вправо. Пробовал использовать анимацию, но она почему-то не срабатывает.

Буду очень благодарен, если кто-нибудь сможет помочь в решении проблемы.

http://codepen.io/Vlastelin/pen/PZbOdY

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 30%;/* изменено для снипета*/
  height: 100px;/* изменено для снипета*/
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 black;

}
.warning-box {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 10px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    color: #FFB700;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    line-height: 1;
}
.warning-box p {
  display: none;
}
.warning-box .fa {
  color: #ffc107;
  font-size: 19px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
}
.warning-box:hover {
  width: 160px;
  border: 1px solid #ff8600;
  border-radius: 8px;
  translateX: 100px;
  transition: 1s;
}
.warning-box:hover .fa  {
  color: #ff8600;
  transition: 200ms;
}
.warning-box:hover .text {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
  color: #ff8600;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="block">
  <div class="warning-box">
    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle">&nbsp</i>&nbsp
    <p class="text">This app is no longer available</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на сайт. Обратите внимание, что код, выполняемый в браузере можно сделать воспроизводимым прямо в тексте вопроса без ссылок на внешрие источники (вы примерно так и сделали, но не добавили CSS). Код, не выполняемый в браузере принято оформлять как код, а не как сниппет

Comment: Хорошо, я приму к сведению, сейчас отредактировать свой вопрос, похоже, уже не могу.

Comment: отредактировать вопрос можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: Всем большое спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо поставить на `.warning-box .text` стиль `width: 0px` изначально. Это блок спрячет.
А на `.warning-box:hover .text` поставить `width: 150px;` и добавить `transition`, тогда будет выезжать :)

Также обратите внимание на `white-space: nowrap; overflow:hidden;`. Это нужно, чтобы текст принудительно вставал в одну строчку.

Вот типа такого:
(из вашего примера были изменены только `.warning-box .text` и `.warning-box:hover .text`.)

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 30%;/* изменено для снипета*/
  height: 100px;/* изменено для снипета*/
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 black;

}
.warning-box {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 10px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    color: #FFB700;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    line-height: 1;
}
.warning-box p {
  display: none;
}
.warning-box .fa {
  color: #ffc107;
  font-size: 19px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
}
.warning-box:hover {
  width: 160px;
  border: 1px solid #ff8600;
  border-radius: 8px;
  translateX: 100px;
  transition: 1s;
}
.warning-box:hover .fa  {
  color: #ff8600;
  transition: 200ms;
}
.warning-box .text {
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 200ms;
  top: 2px;
  left: 10px;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
  color: #ff8600;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.warning-box:hover .text {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="block">
  <div class="warning-box">
    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle">&nbsp</i>&nbsp
    <p class="text">This app is no longer available</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще один вариант, добавить в класс `.warning-box` свойства `overflow:hidden` и установить начальную ширину, в данном случае `width:20px;`

```css
  
.block {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 black;

}
.warning-box {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 10px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    color: #FFB700;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    line-height: 1;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:20px;
}
.warning-box p {
  display: none;
}
.warning-box .fa {
  color: #ffc107;
  font-size: 19px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
}
.warning-box:hover {
  width: 160px;
  border: 1px solid #ff8600;
  border-radius: 8px;
  translateX: 100px;
  transition: 1s;
  
}
.warning-box:hover .fa  {
  color: #ff8600;
  transition: 200ms;
}
.warning-box:hover .text {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
  color: #ff8600;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="block">
  <div class="warning-box">
    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle">&nbsp</i>&nbsp
    <p class="text">This app is no longer available</p>
  </div>
</div>
```